# Tela branca antes da inicialização do Splash Screen

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

Criei um Splash Screen que funciona normalmente, porém na abertura do aplicativo ao invés de entrar direto no Splash, ele executa uma tela branca.

Splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splash"
    android:layout_width="154dp"
    android:layout_height="217dp"
    android:background="@drawable/logo" />
```

Classe

```js
package empresa.example.easyfood;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Timer da splash screen
    private  static  int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            /*
             * Exibindo splash com um timer.
             */
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Esse método será executado sempre que o timer acabar
                // E inicia a activity principal
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, CadastroLogin.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // Fecha esta activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

Como faço para tirar tela branca?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode definir a cor da janela em seu arquivo de estilo

```
 <style name="AppThemeDefault" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
   ...
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/cor</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/cor</item>
   ...
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se a SplashActivity é a activity LAUCHER, isso provavelmente é o aparelho que pode ter um hardware mais modesto, e está carregando o app.

Para verificar se a SplashActivity é a activity laucher (inicial), basta abrir o Arquivo AndroidManifest.xml e ver se, na anotação da activity consta o atributo abaixo:

```
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity ">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Atente-se aos itens dentro da tag **intent-filter**:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Eles que definem que essa activity é a inicial e que é ela a executada quando o app é iniciado.

Se a SplashActivity for de fato a Activity inicial, então a tela branca é do carregamento do app mesmo. Se não, faça com que a SplashScreen seja a inicia acidionando o conteúdo acima na tag intent-filter dela no arquivo do Android Manifest, e apague qualquer que seja a Activity que estava como Laucher anteriormente.